# How does `nullable=False` work in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

From SQLAlchemy docs:

> nullable – If set to the default of True, indicates the column will be
>   rendered as allowing NULL, else it’s rendered as NOT NULL. This
>   parameter is only used when issuing CREATE TABLE statements.

I thought setting `nullable=True` for a Column basically made that Column required. For example:

```
class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'locations'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    latitude = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    ...
```

However, when I create a `Location` instance without a latitude field, I do not get an error!

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 19 2014, 16:02:00)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> Location(latitude=None)
<app.models.Location object at 0x10dce9dd0>
```

What is going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718469/validation-in-sqlalchemy#comment31059318_20718469

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The doc you reference explains the issue:

> This parameter is only used when issuing CREATE TABLE statements.

If you originally created your database without `nullable=False` (or created it in some other way, separate from SQLAlchemy, without `NOT NULL` on that column), then your database *column* doesn't have that constraint information. This information lives in reference to the database column, not to a particular instance you are creating/inserting.

Changing the SQLAlchemy table creation, without rebuilding your tables, means changes will not be reflected. As a link in a comment explains, SQLAlchemy is not doing the validation at that level (you would need to use the `@validates` decorator or some other such thing).

Answer (score 7):

When you first created a `Location` instance and committed it to  the database, was `nullable` set to `True`? if so, sqlalchemy will NOT allow you to subsequently reset the `nullable` parameter to `False`.

You would have to migrate your database using Alembic.

Comment: To be precise - it doesn't matter when they created the `Location` instance, it matters when/how they created the table in whatever SQL backend they are using. Even restarting the Python code (which would reload the `db.Model`) would not solve the problem unless the SQL tables themselves are being recreated. I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but the wording was a little ambiguous. Also, they don't NEED to use `Alembic`; what they NEED is to actually add the `NOT NULL` constraint to their SQL table.