# Why does adding invalid records not trigger an exception until commit? How should this error be handled?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.4 on Python 3.8 with a PostgreSQL database. When I try to add new records to the database, if there is an error, `add` does not generate any exceptions. Instead, `commit` will complain if anything isn't right.

Note that this is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192062/how-does-nullable-false-work-in-sqlalchemy). The problem there was that the user did not initially set `nullable=False` when the database was created. That clearly isn't the case here, as you can see in the MRE, the database schema is created from scratch. This also doesn't address my question about managing the error.

Here is a MRE, adding a record with null entries that are marked as not nullable:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'account'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(email='{email}', name='{name}'')>".format(
            email=self.email, name=self.name
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://{username}:{password}@127.0.0.1/{db_name}')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    Session = sessionmaker(engine)

    with Session() as session:
        session.begin()
        try:
            account = session.add(User())
        except Exception as e:
            print('Failed to add user: {error}'.format(error=str(e)))  # This won't be printed
            session.rollback()
            exit()

        try:
            session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Failed to commit add user: {error}'.format(error=str(e)))  # The error happens here
            exit()

        print('Successfully added user')
```

This is unexpected because the [SQLAlchemy page on sessions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#what-does-the-session-do) doesn't describe this, it suggests that `commit` won't cause any errors. Only `add` is checked for an exception.

**1. Am I doing something wrong?**

Why does this not behave like the docs suggest it should?

**2. How do I manage this error? Can I also call `rollback` after catching an error from commit?**

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlalchemy or python, but the docu you have linked states: 'Session.add() is used to place instances in the session. For transient (i.e. brand new) instances, this will have the effect of an INSERT taking place for those instances **upon the next flush**.' You could also have [deferred constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-set-constraints.html) in your table definition which have to be fulfilled at transaction end, not immediately. So, commit can surely throw an exception.

Comment: See [the SQLAlchemy docs for `nullable`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=column#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.nullable), especially the part that says "This parameter is only used when issuing CREATE TABLE statements."

Comment: What is the error?