sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation)
I came across similar questions to IntegrityError sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) but none of those answer my question. I have models.py:
class UsersT(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "userst"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    mobile_number = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True, unique=True)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    createdby = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    modified = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now(), nullable=True)
    modifiedby = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    statusreason = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)


and the RegisterUser endpoint in app.py:
class RegisterUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  # parser is the instance for RequestParser class
        parser.add_argument('email', type=str, required=False)
        parser.add_argument('mobile_number', type=str, required=False)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        email = args.get('email')
        mobile_number = args.get('mobile_number')

        print("Received email:", email)
        print("Received mobile_number:", mobile_number)


        # initialize new_user variable with None
        new_user = None
        
        # check if either email or mobile number is provided
        if not email and not mobile_number:
            return jsonify({'error': 'email or mobile number is required'}), 400
        
        # if both email and mobile number are provided
        if email and mobile_number:
            # prioritize mobile number over email
            new_user = UsersT(mobile_number=mobile_number)
            entered_value = mobile_number # the entered_value variable is set to the user's entered value

        # check if the user already exists in the database
        if email:
            existing_user = UsersT.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
            if existing_user:
                return jsonify({'error': 'email already exists. try logging in'}), 400
            else: 
                new_user = UsersT(email=email)
                entered_value = email

        elif mobile_number:
            existing_user = UsersT.query.filter_by(mobile_number=mobile_number).first()
            if existing_user:
                return jsonify({'error': 'mobile number already exists. try logging in'}), 400
            else:
                new_user = UsersT(mobile_number=mobile_number)
                entered_value = mobile_number # the entered_value variable is set to the user's entered value



        # commit the new user to the database if new_user is defined
        if new_user:
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            # if new_user is created, send the user's id and entered value
            return "User registered successfully", jsonify({'user_id': new_user.id, 'entered_value': entered_value}), 200

        else:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No valid user data provided'}), 400
        
        # get the user_id of the new user
        user_id = new_user.id


When I run the Flask app, I didn't get any errors in the VScode terminal, but when I tried to use POST method for the /registeruser endpoint in Postman, I inserted the following JSON body:
{   
    "mobile_number": "0123456789",
    "email": "johndoe@gm.com"
}

I keep getting the error:
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation)
null value in column "mobile_number" of relation "userst" violates
not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (25, johndoe@gm.com,
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2024-05-10
13:35:36.864429+05:30, null, 2024-05-10 13:35:36.864429+05:30, null,
null, null). [SQL: INSERT INTO userst (email, city, mobile_number,
created, createdby, modified, modifiedby, status, statusreason) VALUES
(%(email)s, %(city)s, %(mobile_number)s, now(), %(createdby)s, now(),
%(modifiedby)s, %(status)s, %(statusreason)s) RETURNING userst.id,
userst.created, userst.modified] [parameters: {'email':
'johndoe@gm.com', 'city': None, 'mobile_number': None, 'createdby':
None, 'modifiedby': None, 'status': None, 'statusreason': None
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)
. 

I was expecting both the email and mobile_numbers rows to be inserted in the UsersT table in pgadmin.
EDIT: Thank you guys! After making the changes for those two problems pointed out by @Adrian Klaver: setting mobile_number to NULL, (since I also need to register the user with email only), and changing the code, this worked:
        email = args.get('email')
        mobile_number = args.get('mobile_number')

        print("Received email:", email)
        print("Received mobile_number:", mobile_number)


        # initialize new_user variable with None
        new_user = None
        
        # Check if either email or mobile number is provided
        if not email and not mobile_number:
            return jsonify({'error': 'email or mobile number is required'}), 400

        # Check if the user already exists
        if mobile_number:
            existing_user = UsersT.query.filter_by(mobile_number=mobile_number).first()
        else:
            existing_user = UsersT.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        # If user already exists, return error
        if existing_user:
            return jsonify({'error': 'User already exists'}), 400

        # prioritize mobile number over email
        if mobile_number:
            new_user = UsersT(mobile_number=mobile_number)
            entered_value = mobile_number
        else:
            new_user = UsersT(email=email)
            entered_value = email

        # commit the new user to the database if new_user is defined
        if new_user:
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            # if new_user is created, send the user's id and entered value
            return {'user_id': new_user.id, 'entered_value': entered_value}, 200

        else:
            return jsonify({'error': 'No valid user data provided'}), 400



There are locations where you overwrite new_user with either only email or only mobile_number, hence the errror.

I guessing it is because of what is explained in the answer to this SO question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192062/how-does-nullable-false-work-in-sqlalchemy. Namely that mobile_number is actually set NOT NULL in the database table and doing mobile_number = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True, unique=True) has no effect on that as it would  only come into play if the table where initially by SQLAlchemy from the model.

As to why you get into this state, per @snakecharmerb, you have alternate versions of new_user as determined by if email: <...> elif mobile_number: <...>. Since email comes first  and this, { "mobile_number": "0123456789",   "email": "johndoe@gm.com"} has an email you will get a new_user with only  email set to "johndoe@gm.com"  and mobile_phone set to None/Null. If you want this to work you need to add the other value(email or mobile_phone), if it exists, to  new_user.
